# Less "aggressive" synonym for "left the company"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that you would use when someone has left a company. This can be because the person quit, they are fired, retired,...
I was thinking about **Discharged** but that seems like it only means fired.
I thought of other words like **Out of service** but that just feels like it's a machine.
Is there a single word that I can use to describe this status?

I really need it to be a single word. 
I want to use it like a kind of “stamp”
to add over the person’s profile picture in our intranet.

Comment: Erm... but *He has left the company* IS often a "less aggressive" version of *The company sacked him.* An even more "weasely" euphemism is *The company **had to let him go***.

Comment: _He and the company have **parted ways**_ or _He has **separated from** the company_ or _He **no longer works for** the company_ ...

Comment: How hard is your requirement that it be a single word? Is that simply preferable, or is that an absolute requirement?

Comment: I really need it to be a single word. I want to use it like a kind of "stamp" to add over the person's profile picture in our intranet.

Comment: Oh, does that mean your single word even needs to cover people who've *died*? And at the other extreme of finality, interns who've completed their internships and have already accepted offers to return after they graduate? That's quite a range there.

Comment: Possibly 'to resign' or 'to hand in one's notice' (possibly a UK English expression, but I am unsure).

Comment: What's wrong with the single word "Left"?

Comment: But there may be an argument for not retaining their image once they have left the company, so simply a blank/placeholder image might convey their status just as well, as well as allowing more room for more text.

Comment: "**Gone**" would work.

Comment: The kindest I have heard is that they *Chose another path* or that they *Went in a different direction*. Me, I just got canned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any person who leaves a company for whatever reason becomes an **[ex](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/ex.html) employee**.
The OP can join the compound with a hyphen, i.e. ex-employee, if a single-word is absolutely necessary. Google reports [thousands](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20ex-employee%22&num=20&ei=XiZsW56NHeaB0wLb9I3wCw&start=60&sa=N&biw=1309&bih=619) of instances using this form.

Comment: Although not exactly what I was looking for, this might be the closest answer.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a single word for what you are asking. Terminating employment is generally so fraught with circumstances and combinations of circumstances (voluntary/involuntary, for cause/down-sizing, retiring/found a better job, personality conflict, etc.) that descriptions will either be very specific or deliberately obscure. Neither case lends itself to single words.

Answer (score 1):

What about "Bob *switched/changed* companies"?

Comment: I thought of that, but I really need a single word. Also this couldn't be used when the person retired.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all pejorative, and suggests they've more to do:

> **alumnus**
>   plural **alumni**
>   2 : a person who is a former member, employee, contributor, or inmate
>    - *a Saturday Night Live **alumnus***
>    --[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alumnus)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "**resign**" is a good and more formal alternative. **"Vacate"** is also another formal verb with the same meaning.

```
He resigned from his job.
```

or something like

```
He will vacate his position next week.
```

Comment: Do those words not indicate that the decision to quit was his alone? It doesn't feel like you would say resigned when the person was fired or went into retirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use "exited" (ie, they have exited the company).  It's very non-descript as to why they left and I feel not aggressive at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the word "unavailable"; it is vague enough to cover every conceivable reason for the employee not being employed there, and it fits on a stamp.

Comment: Unavailable suggests that they might become available at some later stage.